# Error laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Cuando ejecuto este método me dice que esta protegido. No entiendo porque no puedo recuperar a un usuario de un guard.

```
Auth::guard('web')->user;
```

Error

```
Error
Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$user
```

Comment: Es una propiedad protegida, debes acceder como función `Auth::guard('web')->user()`, es decir, te faltan los paréntesis.

Comment: Lo siento amigo, ni poniendo los paréntesis se quita el error. Creo que es porque estaba utilizando sanctum. Porque nunca me había pasado este problema. En todas maneras cambie a passport.

Comment: Creo que deberías llamar a la propiedad de la variable user,  algo asi como Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name;

Comment: Creo que la informacion sobre que estabas usando era importante, no?